# In Highcharts, can I access the x and y value in various parts of the chart code? I want to show a plot line at certain x values being plotted

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to be able to check if the y value being plotted is zero, and if it is I want to show a green plot line at that corresponding x value.

Does this make sense and is it doable?

I can chart the plot lines in xAxis like this:

```
xAxis: {
                        type: "datetime",
                        tickInterval: 24*60*60*1000,
                        labels: {
                            format: this.active_filter == "week" ? '{value:%a}' : '{value:%b %e}',
                        },
                        min: start_date_unix*1000,
                        max: end_date_unix*1000,
                        plotLines: [{
                            color: '#FF0000',
                            width: 2,
                            value: VALUE
                        }]
                    },
```

But where value is I want to check the y value of the bar being graphed.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify every part of the chart dynamically and access all of the required values. Below you can find an example of how to perform a dynamic operation:

```
const chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {...});

const plotLines = [];

chart.series[0].points.forEach(point => {
  if (point.y === 0) {
    plotLines.push({
      value: point.x,
      color: 'green'
    });
  }
});

chart.xAxis[0].update({
  plotLines
});
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6nvx4bep/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart